# JavaScript operator ++

Tags: javascript, operators

i'm having this js code and i can't understand why does the last number is 12 and why it starts counting from 8. Why doen't it strat from 10 and end at 14?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var k;
for (k=010; k<015; k++)
{
document.write(" "+k);
document.write("<br>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The bigger question here is: Why did you start those numbers with zeroes? :-)

Comment: Because i wanted ti see how it would look like if there is a zero in front of the numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `0` at the start of your numbers causes the language to interpret them as base 8 ("octal") values. `010` is `8`, and `015` is `13`.

If you remove the leading `0` characters from your numbers, it will work.

The use of a leading `0` to indicate octal dates back to (at least) C.

Comment: ...in a JavaScript implementation that does that; it's [not required by the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1) (and as it's invalid in strict mode, one could argue it's actively *discouraged*).

Comment: "at least" indeed: It goes back *one level prior*, [to the language B](https://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html#Section2_4). The one before that, BCPL, used `#` instead ([pdf](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/bcpl_reference_manual.pdf)). ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, that's true. Maybe in 5 years or so all the random "learn you a javascript" sites out there will finally have started telling people to put `"use strict";` at the top of each script block :)

Comment: That would be nice. :-)